# Can't write to SQLite database in WPF project

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, sqlite

Having one of those tear-your-hair-out evenings.

I'm porting a WPF project over from using access and OleDBConnection to using SQLite and SQLiteConnection. My application reads from the project upon load, and then writes to it later after some form entry.

The reading works fine, using this code:

```
private void InitialiseDB()
    {
                   connString = "data source = PortalDB.db";

        conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);

                            SQLiteCommand AttendeeCmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM AttendeeNames", conn);
                            SQLiteCommand SignInOutsCmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT SignTime, UserID, SignType FROM SignInOuts", conn);

            conn.Open();

            SQLiteDataAdapter AttendeeAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(AttendeeCmd);
            SQLiteDataAdapter SignInOutsAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SignInOutsCmd);


            //Clear current datatables
            AttendeeNamesTable.Clear();
            SignInOutsTable.Clear();
            //Fill data tables from adapters
            AttendeeAdapter.Fill(AttendeeNamesTable);
            SignInOutsAdapter.Fill(SignInOutsTable);
            conn.Close();

    }
```

But for the life of me I can't get the writing to work, It doesn't throw any errors or exceptions, it just doesn't write to the database. That code looks like this, with the data being passed in from having just been aded to a local DataTable:

```
private void SyncUpDB(int SignUserId, string SignType, DateTime SignTime)
       {

        //...Open the connection...
         conn.Open();
         //..Make SQL query by declaring fields to write to (not SignID) and where to get the data from. Strings need single quote, numbers do not.
         String SyncUpDBQuery = "INSERT INTO SignInOuts (SignTime,UserID,SignType) VALUES('" + SignTime + "', " + SignUserId + ", '" + SignType + "')";
         //...Make new database command from query
         SQLiteCommand SyncUpDBCommand = new SQLiteCommand(SyncUpDBQuery, conn);
         //...And execute on database
         SyncUpDBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

As I say, this used to work perfectly with Access, just won't play ball with SQLite... any ideas?

Comment: Execute a SELECT and log the result right in `SyncUpDB`. What happens?

Comment: @CL. You mean to test whether it's just the insert command that's having a problem, or the connection to the database itself?
Just tried that, a select command works, it can fill a table from that method. 
I've also tried applying the Insert query directly to the database and that works too...

Comment: Does the just-inserted row show up in the SELECT?